# why are all subsets of a countable standard Borel space measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

I frequently read that in finite or countable [standard Borel spaces](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Standard_Borel_space) every subset is measurable, unfortunately never with a full proof (so this must be a standard argument). Can somebody please provide such a proof or a reference? Thank you very much!

Comment: **Hint:** It's probably easier to discover a proof of the following stronger result — *Every  subset is an* $F_{\sigma}$ *set.*

Comment: You haven't seen a detailed proof because this is so obvious. We're talking about the Borel subsets of a metric space.  Any singleton $\{x\}$ is Borel (because it's the intersection of countably many open balls, **or** because it's a closed set...) and a countable union of Borel sets is a Borel set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a metric space every singleton is closed, hence is a Borel-set.

If the space is countable then every subset can be written as a countable union of singletons which is a Borel-set.